# Postgresql Date Range - Most Efficient Want To Query Rows Prior To a Date

Tags: postgresql, date-range

Consider a table with a duration field that is a daterange.

Is there any more efficient way to query for records with durations that have passed a certain date than the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE upper(duration) < '2021-11-01'::date;
```

I would imagine running a function (upper) on every row would be slower than something that could natively utilize an index? Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: Something like `select daterange('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31', '()') << daterange('2021-11-01',null); t` or `select daterange('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31', '()') @> '2021-11-01'::date;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the “strictly left of” operator `<<` like this:

```
WHERE duration << DATERANGE '[2021-11-01,2021-11-01]'´;
```

Sure, the operator will be more expensive, but you save the extra function call. I'd expect that to be a win, but you should test it with a large table.